Is there a geometric theory of transcendental equations?
As you know, transcendental functions can be represented by infinite series expansions. Which means that transcendental equations can be expressed as polynomials of (countably)infinite degree. The idea would be generalizing the concept of an algebraic variety to a subset of an infinite dimensional space representing the solutions to a set of transcendental equations. Is there an actual theory of this? What would be the term for an infinite dimensional algebraic variety?

I believe the theory involves not power series, but analytic functions.

Working with power series is unrelated to making the number of variables infinite. There's some stuff like this in the theory of O-minimal structures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/O-minimal_theory
